# Yii2 как сделать ID уникальным или рандомным для поста?

Tags: php, yii2

Чтобы пользователь не мог перебирать id самостоятельно в ссылке.

Comment: Посмотрите на `uniqid()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте

В таблицу с постом добавляем поле `slug`

В моделе при сохранении поста генерируем уникальное значение:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $this->slug = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8); // 8 - длина строки, пример
    return parent::beforeSave($insert); 
}
```

В контроллере `аctionView($id)` меняем на что-то вроде:

```
public function actionView($slug) {
   $model = Post::findOne(['slug' => $slug]);
   // валидация и прочий код
   return $this->render('view', [
       'model' => $model,
   ]);
}
```

Теперь просмотр поста не будет работать по `id`, а будет доступен только по `slug`

Ссылка на пост будет формироваться так:

```
Url::toRoute(['posts/view', 'slug' => $slug]);
```

Решение рабочее, но не очень "красивое", можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями, например [skeeks-semenov/yii2-slug-behavior](https://github.com/skeeks-semenov/yii2-slug-behavior)